# MS SQL Server with EF Core 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths' with Delete Behavior SetNull

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I really thought I'd understood the EF Core delete behavior constraints concerning MS SQL Server, but obviously I don't :-(

Introducing a foreign key with delete behavior **"set null"** leads to the following exception when updating the database:

> ALTER TABLE [AppointmentParticipations] ADD CONSTRAINT
>   [FK_AppointmentParticipations_SelectValueMappings_ResultId] FOREIGN
>   KEY ([ResultId]) REFERENCES [SelectValueMappings] ([Id]) ON DELETE SET
>   NULL; |               url: |               action:  Failed executing
>   DbCommand (17ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text',
>   CommandTimeout='30'] ALTER TABLE [AppointmentParticipations] ADD
>   CONSTRAINT [FK_AppointmentParticipations_SelectValueMappings_ResultId]
>   FOREIGN KEY ([ResultId]) REFERENCES [SelectValueMappings] ([Id]) ON
>   DELETE SET NULL; Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_AppointmentParticipations_SelectValueMappings_ResultId' on table
>   'AppointmentParticipations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade
>   paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify
>   other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index.
>   See previous errors.    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String
>   methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache,
>   Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject
>   parameterObject)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
>   migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
>   targetMigration)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String
>   targetMigration, String contextType)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action
>   action) ClientConnectionId:40c35c1b-5be2-4cdc-957d-2e9ade19aceb Error
>   Number:1785,State:0,Class:16 Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_AppointmentParticipations_SelectValueMappings_ResultId' on table
>   'AppointmentParticipations' may cause cycles or multiple cascade
>   paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify
>   other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could not create constraint or index.
>   See previous errors.

The concerned class:

```
public class AppointmentParticipation : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; private set; }
    public Guid AppointmentId { get; private set; }
    public virtual Appointment Appointment { get; private set; }
    public Guid? ResultId { get; private set; }
    public virtual SelectValueMapping Result { get; private set; }
    public Guid? PredictionId { get; private set; }
    public virtual SelectValueMapping Prediction { get; private set; }
}
```

The entity type configuration:

```
 public class AppointmentParticipationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AppointmentParticipation>
   {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AppointmentParticipation> builder)
        {
            builder
                .HasOne(e => e.Person)
                .WithMany(p => p.AppointmentParticipations)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.PersonId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder
                .HasOne(e => e.Appointment)
                .WithMany(a => a.AppointmentParticipations)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.AppointmentId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder
                .HasOne(e => e.Result)
                .WithMany(c => c.AppointmentParticipationsAsResult)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ResultId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);

            builder
                .HasOne(e => e.Prediction)
                .WithMany(c => c.AppointmentParticipationsAsPrediction)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.PredictionId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
        }
    }
```

Why may setting a foreign key to null cause cycles or multiple cascade paths? I thought that this can only be the case with delete behavior cascade? I'm really confused :-(

Comment: This really is question for SqlServer. EF Core has nothing to do with it, as you can see the exception is from database. And other databases (Oracle for instance) have no issues with multiple cascade paths at all.

Comment: Ok, thent it's a SQL Server issue. But what is its problem with Delete Behavior "Set Null"?